# parse_failed error occured in augeas,why this error occur and how to fix this issue?

Tags: properties, dependency-properties, properties-file, attached-properties, augeas

I want to edit file "myfileDB.properties" using augeas. so used Properties.lns.
but it made error "parse_failed"and some time "parse_skel_failed". explain the root cause of this error and solve this issue.

```
 augtool> print /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/
 /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error = "parse_failed"
 /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/pos = "17835"
 /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/line = "318"
 /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/char = "0"
 /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/lens = "/usr/share  /augeas/lenses/dist/properties.aug:50.25-.100:"
 /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/message = "Iterated lens matched less than it should"

   /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error = "parse_skel_failed"
   /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/pos = "4844943"
   /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/line = "53707"
   /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/char = "0"
   /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/lens = "/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/simplevars.aug:34.10-.46:"
   /augeas/files/root/yog/myfileDB.properties/error/message = "Iterated lens matched less than it should"
```

Comment: Can you paste line 318 of your properties file?

Comment: Also, it seems you actually have two pastes of two different augtool runs in your question, with a fix done to the file between them...